# Create a socket server using python, and access it from another network\country

Tags: python, sockets, networking, port

How can I create a socket server, and access it from another network\country? I create a server using java. I want to connect the server from another network (like a hotel's wi-fi)

How can I do that?

My python server:

```
def start():
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((socket.gethostname(), 2201))


    print("Waiting for connection...\n")

    while True:
        server.listen()
        (client, (ipNum, portNum)) = server.accept()

        message = str(client.recv(32).decode())

        if(message != ""):
            print("Client: " + message)

            Command(message.lower())

            print("Server: " + BackMessage)

        else:
            time.sleep(0.05)
start() # Start the server
```

Python client:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 2001 # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b'Hello, world')
    data = s.recv(1024)

print('Received', repr(data))
```

It's not working when I switch connections only when I'm in the same network with the server. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is not enough to add a comment, so I put an answer here.

If server locate in a local area network, it cannot be found be a client in another local area network.

You should put the server at the WAN(Wide Area Network) or use NAT(Network Address Translation) + nat traversal.

Comment: Do you have an example or some tutorial?

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92b-jjBURkw)  may helps you understand the problem you encountered.@איתמרשיאון

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8TurViPVJ0&t=13s) explains the NAT traversal.@איתמרשיאון